# GNU Makefile for compiling each chapter with its own reference

Tags: bibtex, compiling, makefile

My book structure is like:

```
book.tex
chapter/ch1.tex
       /ch2.tex
ref/ch1.bib
   /ch2.bib
```

As each chapter of my book is required to has its own reference thus I used `chapterbib` package and fed each chapter tex file with corresponding bib file. Finally I could manage to compile the book as following bash commands:

```
xelatex book
bibtex chapter/ch1
bibtex chapter/ch2
xelatex book
xelatex book
```

Now my question is that, how could I compile the book by writing the Makefile? My current script does no work at all.

```
TEXFILE := book
CHAPTERDIR := chapter
CHAPTERS := $(wildcard $(CHAPTERDIR)/*.tex)
TEXENGINE=xelatex
BIBTEX=bibtex
BUILDTEX=$(TEXENGINE) $(TEXFILE)

all:
    $(BUILDTEX)
    $(shell for chapterSrc in $(CHAPTERS); do \
        chapterSrcName=$(shell basename $(chapterSrc) .tex); \
        $(BIBTEX) $(CHAPTERDIR)/$(chapterSrcName); \
    done)
    $(BUILDTEX)
    $(BUILDTEX)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: untested code.  *Should* work in GNU Make.

```
TEXFILE := book
CHAPTERDIR := chapter
CHAPTERS := $(wildcard $(CHAPTERDIR)/*.tex)
BIBS := $(patsubst %.tex,%,$(CHAPTERS))
TEXENGINE=xelatex
BIBTEX=bibtex
BUILDTEX=$(TEXENGINE) $(TEXFILE)

all:
    $(BUILDTEX)
    for c in $(BIBS); do \
        $(BIBTEX) $$c; \
        done;
    $(BUILDTEX)
    $(BUILDTEX)
```